# PHPMailer Using Gmail Not Sending

Tags: php

I am using PHP Mailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) and for some reason it is not working with gmail. Does anyone know if there are any other settings I should be using?

```
 function send_email($mail_content,$subject,$email,$name)
        {
            include_once('third-party/mail/phpmailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php');     
            $php_mailer_mail = new PHPMailer;   
            $php_mailer_mail->isSMTP();
            $php_mailer_mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $php_mailer_mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $php_mailer_mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';
            $php_mailer_mail->Password = 'password';
            $php_mailer_mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $php_mailer_mail->Port = 465;
            $php_mailer_mail->From = 'email@gmail.com';
            $php_mailer_mail->FromName = 'Me';
            $php_mailer_mail->addAddress($email, $name);  
            $php_mailer_mail->isHTML(true);
            $php_mailer_mail->Subject = $subject;
            $php_mailer_mail->Body = $mail_content;
            $php_mailer_mail->send();
        }
```

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: No emails coming through

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable IMAP in your gmail settings.  smtp is not IMAP, but Google will discard smtp requests for your account unless that is enabled in your account settings.

You may also want to try port 587 with TLS encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors?

if `$php_mailer_mail->send();` returns `false` you may inspect `$php_mailer_mail->ErrorInfo`

Anyway you should use port `587` and `tls` instead of `ssl`.

```
$php_mailer_mail->Port = 587;
$php_mailer_mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```

You may take a look at

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps

Furthermore (from the example at the link above)

> SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
>   This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that

```
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');
```

This line must be at the beginning of the script.
Of course double-check username and password.

Hope it helps...